# There is a problem of using 2 foreignkeys in one table in flask in sqlite database

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Here I want to use User(table) 2 foreignKeys in my product table first as my customer and second as my seller but i get some problems with that

```
from app import db, login
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash,generate_password_hash
from flask_login import UserMixin


@login.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(int(id))

#This is the user class of seller and customer 
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String, index=True, nullable = False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String, index=True, nullable = False)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True, nullable = False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True, nullable = False)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable = False)
    gender = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable = False)
    user_type = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable = False)
    phone_no = db.Column(db.String(15),index=True, unique=True, nullable = False)
    wallet_amount = db.Column(db.Float)
    address = db.Column(db.Text)
    products = db.relationship('Product', backref = 'author', lazy = 'dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {}>'.format(self.username)

    def set_password(self,password):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def check_password(self,password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash,password)
```

#Product class contains 2 foreignkeys of User class but get some errors

```
class Product(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(70), index = True,nullable = False)
    description = db.Column(db.Text, nullable = False)
    customer_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    seller_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    images = db.Column(db.Text, nullable = False)


    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Product {}>'.format(self.name)
```

Answer (score -1):

"""
The problem is there is only one column in the user class but we are using 2 foreign_keys so that we have to create 2 columns first is products_seller and second is products_customer and add one extra argument which is forenign)keys and the suitable columns of Product table fields on it so now it is done and i think only this one possible solution in my mind if anyone know better then please suggest me.
"""
from app import db, login
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash,generate_password_hash
from flask_login import UserMixin

```
@login.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(int(id))

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String, index=True, nullable = False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String, index=True, nullable = False)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True, nullable = False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True, nullable = False)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable = False)
    gender = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable = False)
    user_type = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable = False)
    phone_no = db.Column(db.String(15),index=True, unique=True, nullable = False)
    wallet_amount = db.Column(db.Float)
    address = db.Column(db.Text)
    products_seller = db.relationship('Product', backref = 'author_seller', lazy = 'dynamic', foreign_keys = 'Product.customer_id')
    products_customer = db.relationship('Product', backref = 'author_customer', lazy = 'dynamic', foreign_keys = 'Product.seller_id' )


    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {}>'.format(self.username)

    def set_password(self,password):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def check_password(self,password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash,password)

class Product(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(70), index = True,nullable = False)
    description = db.Column(db.Text, nullable = False)
    customer_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable = True)
    seller_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable = True)
    images = db.Column(db.Text, nullable = False)


    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Prodect {}>'.format(self.name)
```